# how to download sent2vec library

Tags: pip

So I'm trying to download `sent2vec` (this one: https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec) on windows, and I have issues with that.

to my understanding, pip installs won't work because it will get a different package with the same name.
I tried to download the library by manually git cloning the `sent2vec` and `fastText` libraries and then using `pip install .` (I got the idea from another thread).

When trying to pip install sent2vec, I get this error:

```
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from sent2vec==0.0.0) (1.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.29.13 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from sent2vec==0.0.0) (0.29.32)
Building wheels for collected packages: sent2vec
  Building wheel for sent2vec (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for sent2vec (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sent2vec
Failed to build sent2vec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sent2vec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sent2vec` [requires](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec#setup-and-requirements) Facebook's FastText library which [builds on Unix (Linux distributions and modern Mac OS)](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#requirements). The [list of compiler flags](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/blob/9efbc2dd69f6c737c3a752c9dc5fbb4843d578b6/setup.py#L20) is clearly for GCC, they don't work with MSVC.

The bottom line is: the library cannot be built on w64.

`sent2vec` repository [includes a `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/blob/master/Dockerfile) so you can try to use Docker. Or you can try WSL2. Both the `Dockerfile` and WSL2 run Ubuntu, a Linux distribution.

*Upd*. The `Dockerfile` was not updated in 3 years, [last commit](https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/commit/2ea36dead350145e05aa90f176e1da704120e71c) was on Aug 29, 2019, so it's a bit outdated. The simplest fix currently seems to be editing it after cloning and setting a version in the 1st line: make it `FROM ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: I tried to use the dockerfile but I got error messages about unabling to locate some of the packages (libevent-pthreads-2.1-6).

Comment: @jhon Yep, reproduced. I reported the bug at https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/issues/127 Edit `Dockerfile`, make it `libevent-pthreads-2.1-7`. Or try `FROM ubuntu:18.04`, that works for me.